# If $K\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ is a finitely generated and resdiually finite group but $K$ isn't, can the following abelianization all be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory, semidirect-product, infinite-groups

I am looking for a residually finite semidirect product with the following properties. This is related to this question: [If $K\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ is a finitely generated group but $K$ isn't, can the following abelianization be finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4413788/976076) (Thank you, Derek Holt and Ycor for the answer to my previous question).

Suppose that we have a finitely generated and ***residually finite*** group $G = K\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$, but $K$ is not finitely generated.
Let $T$ be a finite subset of $K$ such that $\langle (0,1), (k,0)\mid k \in T \rangle$ is a generating set of $G$. Let $\phi(n)$ be the automorphism on $K$ corresponding to $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which defines the semi-direct product. Let $H =  \langle T  \rangle$, a finitely generated subgroup of $K$.

Now, suppose in addition, the automorphisms satisfy that
$$\ldots  \phi(-1)(H)  \supsetneqq  \phi(0)(H)   \supsetneqq \phi(1)(H)  \supsetneqq \phi(2)(H)  \ldots \tag{$*$}$$

Because $G$ is residually finite, $H$ is, too. we know that there exists a sequence of nested, normal, finite index subgroups $$H  = N_0 \rhd  N_1  \rhd N_2    \ldots $$ with the trivial intersection.

**Question:** Is it possible that all $N_i$ have finite abelianization, *i.e.* the quotient group $N_i \big/ [N_i,N_i]$ is finite for ***every*** $i$?

**My thoughts so far**: Using the answer from the previous question, here is a group that almost satisfies all the properties: let $H$ be the Grigorchuk group, and we construct $K$ using the ascending HNN-extension with an injective non-surjective endomorphism of $H$. Unfortunately, such $K$ is not residually finite (in general, requiring that the HNN is residually finite is a strong condition), but $K\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies all the other properties.

I think the derive series $H \supset H^{(1)}\supset H^{(2)} \dots $ of $H$ never stablises, and each $H^{(i)}$ is finite index in $H^{(i+1)}$. Also, we can see that $H  \rhd [N_0,N_0] \rhd  [N_1,N_1]  \rhd [N_2,N_2]    \ldots $ is another nested, normal, finite index subgroups of  $H$ with trivial intersection.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423674/given-a-finitely-generated-residually-finite-non-cohopfian-group-g-can-the) seems related.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you!